# apache flink event time processing window processfunction doesn't get called

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Windowing is going on infinite loop or something,i'm printing the data stream after processing but looks like its not hitting that point at all.

Below is my pseudo code.

```
Datastream env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()    
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

Datastream stream = env.addSource() .map(mapping to java object) 
    .filter(filter for specific type of events) 
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
         new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor(Time.seconds(2)){})

Datastream processedStream = stream .keyBy(...)  
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10))) .reduce()

processedStream.print()
```

I added the log to print in reduce function. Logs are getting printed from reduce function. but the stream is not getting printed.

And the streaming source data is history data i.e.. more than 2 months old data. in case of history data streaming anything else needs to be set specifically?

Any inputs would be of great help..

Comment: Did you implement the extractTimestamp method in your BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor?

Comment: `facing similar issue` issue similar to *what*?

Comment: `Below is my pseudo code in java` - so is it java or pseudo-code?

Comment: @David Anderson : yes. I have added that implementation. Assigning timestamp seems to be working fine. But process function on window, which would be called once the window is complete and triggered to emit the records is not getting invoked.

Comment: @greybeard : similar to this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076584/apache-flink-event-time-windows/54830361#54830361

Comment: @AlexYu : edited the question for corrections.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Flink web UI to examine the watermarks, to see if the current watermark has advanced enough to trigger the window. For more information on watermarks, see [the flink training site](https://training.ververica.com/lessons/event-time-watermarks.html).

Comment: Thank you for the response. But can I get some reference for generating watermarks in case of history data streaming that's more than a month old data. In case of BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor we only set allowed lateness which would be w.r.t processing time in flink i.e.. current system time I guess. I have tried with periodic and punctuated watermark assigners. But none worked.

Comment: The beauty of using event time and watermarks is that you can use exactly the same code, whether the events are live data, or historic data from any point in the past. But for that to work properly, your watermarks should only depend on the historic timestamps, and have nothing to do with the current processing time.

Comment: If you want to share a reproducibly failing example, I can take a closer look.

Comment: When I changed the point of invocation for defining window and the pattern for the window configuration, its printing the elements. But now stuck with output handling. Since that sounds to be a different topic/subject than this question, have posted new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861723/handling-output-data-from-flink-datastream. Thanks for you help on this and any inputs on the new question would be of great help.